# How do I synchronize this properly?

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronize

```
public void consumeResponse(OmwListResponse<T> response) {
    synchronized (response.getResultList()) { // XXX this isn't synchronized safely
        for (T t : response.getResultList()) {
            if (!cacheList.contains(t)) {
                cacheList.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The the situation is I don't want anyone to chance *response.getResultList()* or *cacheList* until this method is done. How do I properly do this?

Comment: If `getResultList()` returns a new list on every call, the `synchronized` block isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: Just a reference getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lock object:

```
private static final void LOCK = new Object();
```

and synchronize on that.

Comment: yeah, but could something from the outside this method change response.getResultList() still? Or does LOCK even lock all things inside the synchronized block until it's done?

Comment: @musselwhizzle - a synchronized block will only protect against simultaneous access by cooperating code (that is, code that also synchronizes on the same lock object). If necessary, you can make your `LOCK` object `public` and give it a more meaningful name (e.g., `OMW_RESPONSE_LOCK`). Then synchronize on the lock object with all code that modifies either `response` or `cacheList`. I recommend against nested synchronized blocks because that is a prime source of deadlocks.

Comment: eh...I'm not sure I really want to go down that road. I'd like for my synchronization to be hidden from the implementation. At this point, I'm more likely to make a copy of getResultList and then run my loop. Yes, I'm trying to avoid nested synchronized blocks.

Comment: @musselwhizzle - That still isn't going to protect you against simultaneous modifications of `resultList` while you're making the copy. There's no good way around it: all code that accesses `resultList` needs to synchronize when one or more threads are modifying it.

Comment: Dang, so standard Java approach for synchronization is to make public properties and synchronize on that? That sounds terrible and prone to errors. Why would a nested synchronized blocks be bad in this situation? P.S. Thanks for all the help. You rock, buddy!!!

Comment: @musselwhizzle - That's a common approach. The main reason that nested `synchronized` blocks are dangerous is that all code that locks on two resources must lock in exactly the same order everywhere, or else you have a deadlock just waiting to happen. (Actually, I seem to recall that in Android, you'll get an exception if that situation is detected.)

Comment: @musselwhizzle - By the way, if you can make do with a `Set` (or perhaps a `SortedSet`) instead of a `List` for your cache, then you can replace the body of the block with `cacheSet.addAll(response.getResultList())`. Then you can make `cacheSet` a synchronized set (using the `Collections.synchronizedSet(set)` method) and dispense with synchronizing within your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing cacheList is easy. Just wrap any code your code that uses it in:

```
synchronized(cacheList) {
   // Make changes to cacheList here
}
```

If cacheList is a public member and you're afraid external classes will change it, make it a private member and synchronize the getter and setter. This is the only way since you have no control over what other classes do and it is your responsibility to synchronize your members.

As for response, that is trickier because I don't what an OmwListResponse is. Do you own that class? If so, use the same method as above. If not, you may be out of luck.